# ActionScript: Library implementing a 'set' datatype?

Tags: actionscript, dataset

Has anyone implemented a Set class in ActionScript? Specifically, a Set which is similar to Python's `set` implementation (unordered, unique, O(1) membership, etc).

I'd like to be able to iterate over it using `for each`, perform operations like union and intersection and get a list of all the contained items… Which would all be *possible* to implement using `Dictionary` and `Proxy`, but I'd rather not reimplement it if someone's already done the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a decent enough implementation.

[Link to Collection class](http://snipplr.com/view/8509/as3-collection-class/)

Comment: Hhmm… It doesn't allow duplicates, but the membership is O(N), so it won't quite do for what I'm looking for. It's good to know about though - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Way overkill, but [polygonal_ds](http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/) is a very optimized set of data structures you can use from AS3.